# How to save string index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, char

I have a string whose each character is am storing in a char like

```
char currentLetter;
```

When the loop runs for `i=0` the first letter of the sting is copied to currentLetter. and on `i=1` the second letter is copied. 
However what I want i to save each of the string index of a particular letter.

How can I do that?

Comment: mean you want index of all letter..and letter also..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"Hello World";
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++)
{
    if ([str characterAtIndex:i] == 'o')
        [indexSet addIndex:i];
}

// indexSet now contains all the indexes of the letter 'o' in "str"
// which should be 4 and 7.
```

The [`NSIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSIndexSet) and [`NSMutableIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes are useful for storing indexes because they provide other methods for manipulating and efficiently dealing with indexes.